# iOS While using Agora audio calls joining and leaving the channel shows red color in the status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-streaming, agora.io

I am using Agora SDK for Audio calling. But whenever I join or leave channel I see red color on my status bar. How to avoid this red status bar?? My code is below.

//Initialising

```
self.agoraKit = [AgoraRtcEngineKit sharedEngineWithAppId:self.userManager.agoraAppID delegate:self];
[self.agoraKit enableAudioVolumeIndication:200 smooth:3 report_vad:YES];
[self.agoraKit adjustRecordingSignalVolume: 50];
```

//Join Room

```
[self.agoraKit joinChannelByToken:self.userManager.agoraToken channelId:self.userManager.channelName info:nil uid:[self.userManager.UID integerValue] joinSuccess:^(NSString *channel, NSUInteger uid, NSInteger elapsed) {

}];
```

// Leave Room

```
[self.agoraKit leaveChannel:^(AgoraChannelStats *stat) {

}];
```

In the Background Modes I selected Voice over IP. If I remove that red bar is not coming but audio is not audible in the background.
Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The red status bar is built-in Apple functionality to alert the user to the fact that an app is using the microphone even in the background. There's no way to disable it.

Comment: Can you check apps like Cuddle, Hakuna. Even they are using Audio calling feature with Mic permission. It works without red bar in the background.